# What does $\nabla_k$ mean?

Tags: notation, vectors

> Here the $\nabla_k$ denote that the gradient must be calculated at the point $r_k$.

Suppose I have a scalar function $V = V(\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,\textbf{r}_3)$, where $\textbf{r}_k$ are 3 dimensional vectors defined as $\textbf{r}_k = \textbf{r}_k(x,y,z)$

Now I want to know how this symbol looks like: $\nabla_k$

I think it is like this :
$\nabla_k V = \frac{\partial V}{\partial \textbf{r}_k} = \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial r_{kx}},\frac{\partial V}{\partial r_{ky}},\frac{\partial V}{\partial r_{kz}}\right)$

For the denominator, $\partial r_{kx}$ is the $x$ variable of the kth vector $\textbf{r}_k$ (same for $y$ and $z$).

For an example, if we let $\textbf{r}_1 = \textbf{r}_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, where $x_1,y_1,z_1$ are variables of the $\textbf{r}_1$ vector. Then $\nabla_1 V = \frac{\partial V}{\partial \textbf{r}_1}= \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial V}{\partial y_1},\frac{\partial V}{\partial z_1}\right)$?

> [image]

this cite offers more information: [here](https://archive.org/details/arxiv-physics0410123/page/n5/mode/2up) for equations: 28 and 29.

I understand that this looks like a physics problem, but the notation is mathematical.

This is my expansion of the above(if correct which seems to hold but not sure.):
[image]

Where we go on to define $V$ which is in terms of generalised coordinates $q_i$ instead of $\textbf{r}_k$, thus we can replace the final $\frac{d \tilde V}{d q_i}$ with $\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_i}$ and arrive at the same conclusion as the text shows.

Comment: One need more information about the context of the problem and the origin of the citation. For your interpretation I would use "for" instead of "at" in the description, but English is not my mother language.

Comment: @user , I added the extra information. And I also thought that the "at" should be different-more like respect to the $r_k $vector or something like that. But I am not sure if I under stand it correctly to begin with

Comment: From the edited text I would assume that your interpretation is correct.